# How to present animated movement of a dam?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, animation

I'm want to know how I can represent planimetric and altimetric movement, measured at different times, with animated cards or video.

Which software do I need? How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: thanks guys you are right :)  so im a whould like to represent the mouvment of a dam in the last 10years . I have create cards and graphics describing that . but i wonder if there is an opensource software which allow  me to model this phenomene ..I found a youtube publication which describe what i mean :  link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KC0IhCJ3kvk